# Deletion in FireStore (Latest Snip)

Tags: reactjs, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, es6-modules

I have a Data Table [image: Like this] i want to delete every document inside collection before invoke loadCheckOut.
How can i dow that with latest JS Syntax.
I am using React JS, and it initilize DB from getDb() method so methods like db.collection() not work on it i want a complete moduler solution

```js
 const loadCheckout = async (priceId) => {
    //before adding we must delete existing collection
    const docRef_x = collection(db, `customers/${user.uid}/checkout_sessions`);
    const snapshot = await getDocs(docRef_x);
    const x = await deleteDoc(snapshot);

    const docRef = await addDoc(
      collection(db, `customers/${user.uid}/checkout_sessions`),
      {
        price: priceId,
        success_url: window.location.origin,
        cancel_url: window.location.origin,
      }
    );
    const ref = collection(db, `customers/${user.uid}/checkout_sessions`);
    const snap = onSnapshot(
      ref,
      { includeMetadataChanges: true },
      async (doc) => {
        var error = null,
          sessionId = null;
        var first = true;
        doc.forEach((ele) => {
          if (first) {
            error = ele.data().error;
            sessionId = ele.data().sessionId;
            first = false;
          }
        });
        console.log(sessionId);
        if (error) {
          alert(error);
        }
        if (sessionId) {
          const stripe = await loadStripe(stripe_public_key);
          stripe.redirectToCheckout({ sessionId });
        }
      }
    );
  };
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This won't work:

```
const snapshot = await getDocs(docRef_x);
const x = await deleteDoc(snapshot);
```

The `deleteDoc` function requires a single `DocumentReference`, while your `snapshot` is a `QuerySnapshot`. This has very little to do with the change in syntax, as `snapshot.delete()` also wouldn't have worked in v8 of the SDK and earlier.

To delete the documents in the query snapshot, loop over the results and delete them one by one:

```
snapshot.forEach((doc) => {
  deleteDoc(doc.ref);
});
```